# Huge performance difference between Vector and HashSet

Tags: java, performance, vector, hashset

I have a program which fetches records from database (using Hibernate) and fills them in a `Vector`. There was an issue regarding the performance of the operation and I did a test with the `Vector` replaced by a `HashSet`. With 300000 records, the speed gain is immense - 45 mins to 2 mins!

So my question is, what is causing this huge difference? Is it just the point that all methods in `Vector` are synchronized or the point that internally `Vector` uses an array whereas `HashSet` does not? Or something else?

The code is running in a single thread.

*EDIT*:
The code is only inserting the values in the `Vector` (and in the other case, `HashSet`).

Comment: Without seeing the operations you are performing on the collections, it is difficult to know where the bottleneck is.

Comment: They are different data structures, and as such they obviously have different strengths and weaknesses. Use the one that best suits your needs, and don't be surprised if a bad choice of data structure ruins performance. But as @spender says, without knowing what you actually **do** with those data structures, it's impossible to say why one is faster than the other.

Comment: edited the post to add the operations performed

Comment: Is the vector sorted, or are elements always inserted at the end?

Comment: Indeed - if you could post some actual code, that would help.

Comment: I am simply calling `Vector.add`.

Comment: Are you sure the `Vector` (why not `ArrayList`?) and `HashSet` end up with the same number of elements?

Comment: -1 - for @abhin4v wasting our time with blatant falsehoods like "I am simply calling `Vector.add`".

Comment: +1 for a good example of why code is important when you ask questions. People should read this as an example of how to ask/not ask questions! In the end, we still get a lesson on what some bottlenecks in code _could_ be.

Comment: Show your code - we shouldn't have to see a comment of 'I double checked the code and found that it indeed is doing a !Vector.contains' to find the code you are using.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it's trying to use the `Vector` *as* a set, and checking for the existence of a record before adding it, then filling the vector becomes an O(n^2) operation, compared with O(n) for `HashSet`. It would also become an O(n^2) operation if you insert each element at the start of the vector instead of at the end.

If you're *just* using `collection.add(item)` then I wouldn't expect to see that sort of difference - synchronization isn't *that* slow.

If you can try to test it with different numbers of records, you could see how each version grows as n increases - that would make it easier to work out what's going on.

EDIT: If you're just using `Vector.add` then it sounds like something else could be going on - e.g. your database was behaving differently between your different test runs. Here's a little test application:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
      vector.add("dummy value");
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time taken: " + (end - start) + "ms");
  }
}
```

Output:

> Time taken: 38ms

Now obviously this isn't going to be very accurate - `System.currentTimeMillis` isn't the best way of getting accurate timing - but it's clearly not taking 45 minutes. In other words, you should look elsewhere for the problem, if you *really* are just calling `Vector.add(item)`.

Now, changing the code above to use

```
vector.add(0, "dummy value"); // Insert item at the beginning
```

makes an enormous difference - it takes 42 *seconds* instead of 38ms. That's clearly a lot worse - but it's still a long way from being 45 minutes - and I doubt that my desktop is 60 times as fast as yours.

Comment: There is no explicit check for uniqueness. Just inserting the values.

Comment: @abhin4v: Inserting the values how, exactly? Please post code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Some of the extra time can be explained by string pooling and/or his object just having a mean constructor.

Comment: @DeadMG: Well, there's 43 minutes of difference between Vector and HashSet, supposedly... and those cases would still need to do the same amount of constructor work.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: That's true, I guess.

Comment: I double checked the code and found that it indeed is doing a `!Vector.contains` before adding the value. My apologies for hastily putting the last comment. So the problem is that it is trying to use a `Vector` as a `Set`.

Comment: thats why i suggested to use a profiler, you would have seen instantly that the contains method takes about 95% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are inserting them at the middle or beginning instead of at the end, then the Vector needs to move them all along. Every insert. The hashmap, on the other hand, doesn't really care or have to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Vector is outdated and should not be used anymore. Profile with ArrayList or LinkedList (depends on how you use the list) and you will see the difference (sync vs unsync).
Why are you using Vector in a single threaded application at all?

Comment: btw this is a guess since you provided no code, you should profile your tool so you can see whats so damn slow :D

Answer (score 1):

Vector is synchronized by default; HashSet is not.  That's my guess.  Obtaining a monitor for access takes time.

I don't know if there are reads in your test, but Vector and HashSet are both O(1) if `get()` is used to access Vector entries.

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances, it is *totally implausible* that inserting 300,000 records into a `Vector` will take 43 minutes longer than inserting the same records into a `HashSet`.

However, I think there is a possible explanation of what might be going on.

First, the records coming out of the database must have a very high proportion of duplicates.  Or at least, they must be duplicates according to the semantics of the equals/hashcode methods of your record class.

Next, I think you must be pushing very close to filling up the heap.

So the reason that the `HashSet` solution is so much faster is that it is most of the records are being *replaced* by the `set.add` operation.  By contrast the `Vector` solution is keeping all of the records, and the JVM is spending most of its time trying to squeeze that last `0.05%` of memory by running the GC over, and over and over.

One way to test this theory is to run the `Vector` version of the application with a much bigger heap.

---

Irrespective, the best way to investigate this kind of problem is to run the application using a profiler, and see where all the CPU time is going.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
       if(vector.contains(i)) {
         vector.add("dummy value");
       }
     }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time taken: " + (end - start) + "ms");
  }
}
```

If you check for duplicate element before insert the element in the vector, it will take more time depend upon the size of vector. best way is to use the HashSet for high performance, because Hashset will not allow duplicate and no need to check for duplicate element before inserting.

Answer (score -1):

According to Dr Heinz Kabutz, he said this in one of his [newsletters](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue183.html).

The old Vector class implements serialization in a naive way. They simply do the default serialization, which writes the entire `Object[]` as-is into the stream. Thus if we insert a bunch of elements into the List, then clear it, the difference between Vector and ArrayList is enormous.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class VectorWritingSize {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    test(new LinkedList<String>());
    test(new ArrayList<String>());
    test(new Vector<String>());
  }

  public static void test(List<String> list) throws IOException {
    insertJunk(list);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      list.add("hello world");
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    out.writeObject(list);
    out.close();
    System.out.println(list.getClass().getSimpleName() +
        " used " + baos.toByteArray().length + " bytes");
  }

  private static void insertJunk(List<String> list) {
    for(int i = 0; i<1000 * 1000; i++) {
      list.add("junk");
    }
    list.clear();
  }
}
```

When we run this code, we get the following output:

```
LinkedList used 107 bytes
ArrayList used 117 bytes
Vector used 1310926 bytes
```

Vector can use a staggering amount of bytes when being serialized. The lesson here? **Don't ever use Vector as Lists in objects that are Serializable**. The potential for disaster is too great.

Comment: Dont ever use Vector at all, its only there for legacy reasons.

Comment: This answer is completely irrelevant. It concerns serialization, which isn't the topic.